# Using backing bean value in javascript

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

```
   <h:form prependId="false" id="vt_sel_form">
         <p:panelGrid styleClass="center" columns="2">                     
                        <p:commandButton value="GO" oncomplete="alert(#{test.i})"  actionListener="#{test.testfxn()}" update="@this"/>
         </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

---

```
  import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

    @ViewScoped
    @ManagedBean(name = "test")

    public class TestClass implements Serializable {

        int i ;

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public void setI(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public void testfxn() {        
            setI(i++);
            //i=i+10;
            System.out.println("i" + i);
        }
    }
```

Here, alert(#{test.i}) is always displaying 0. How do i get backing bean value that changes when I click the commandButton. **It works when I click button twice.** It used to work fine when I used *a4j:commandButton*.

Answer (score 2):

That's just because `alert(#{test.i});` is evaluated when the commandButton is *rendered*. You can see the changed value by telling JSF to render the script again:

```
<h:commandButton value="click me" action="#{testClass.testfxn()}">
    <f:ajax render="out" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="out">
    <h:outputScript>
         alert(#{testClass.i});
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I have used oncomplete. Isn't that enough?

Comment: `oncomplete` is rendered when the view is rendered. That's the time your `#{test.i}` is evaluated. It won't be updated when the ajax request finishes. So you need to tell JSF to put your updated `i` somewhere (maybe have it render a hidden input that you can read from an `oncomplete` function).

Comment: How to I change in real time. I did this with richfaces it was working fine. Then when I did it with primefaces it didn't work.

Comment: @kinkajou Please ask a new question and make sure to include the working richfaces code as well as the primefaces variant that fails.

Comment: You mean your initially posted code worked when using `<a4j:commandButton>`? That's probably because RF updates the component that triggered the action. Try `update="@this"` on the Primefaces' commandButton.

Comment: I have added update=":pnlGroup @this" where :pnlGroup is panel outside form. When I click this form twice it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Richfaces where you can directly call javascript function, primefaces you need to have javascript function as:

***`function_name(xhr, status, args)`***

Using listed CommandButton as Example:

```
 <p:commandButton value="GO" oncomplete="alert(#{test.i})"  actionListener="#{test.testfxn()}" update="@this"/>
```

In function test.testfxn() we have:

```
public void testfxn(){    
RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        i = i++;
        reqCtx.addCallbackParam("i", i);
}
```

Here,In function call to backing bean from actionlistener the variables are added to RequestContext.

Now In javascript function:

```
function draw(xhr, status, args) {
    console.log("We are into draw function");
    jsonString = JSON.parse(args.i); //json variable is taken out from args variable.
    console.log("The value of i "+ i);
}
```